# Cannot set imageView in CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, uicollectionviewcell

In my code, I am trying to set the imageView of a UICollectionViewCell. The imageView is called cellImageView in the CollectionViewCell class. When the app loads up it tries to initialize this value, but it doesn't work

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "selectCell", for: indexPath) as! PhraseSelectionCell
    cell.cellImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "lol")
    return cell
}
```

Class of UICollectionViewCell

```
class PhraseSelectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet var cellImageView: UIImageView!

}
```

Comment: Are you sure , image in the assets has the exact same name?

Answer (score 1):

try debugging this way, then you can find where the bug is.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "selectCell", for: indexPath) as! PhraseSelectionCell

//debug 1
if UIImage(named: "lol") == nil {
    print("image is nil, double check image name")
}

//debug 2
if cell.cellImageView == nil {
    print("cellImageView outlet is nil")
}

cell.cellImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "lol")
return cell
```

}

Comment: I got back "cellImageView outlet is nil" what should I do?

Comment: that means cellImageView outlet not properly bound to View.

Comment: What should I do to fix that problem?